# Coordinated traffic lights

Tags: driving, traffic

Is there any city in the world with well-timed traffic lights over a large grid?

I just want to usually hit 10 green lights in a row when going above 40 mph for all 4 directions (during peak traffic time).

It doesn't seem like it would be that difficult (I would start by outlawing left turns), but I'm always frustrated in California. So, where do city engineers do better? I think the government underappreciates the morale/environmental/time benefits of reducing traffic jams.

Comment: How do you drive in four directions at once?

Comment: @phoog You have 4 drivers to check the grid (or 1 driver tests sequentially that all 4 directions work) if you really need an exact experiment. I thought you were making a joke, but then somebody up-voted your comment, so responding seriously.

Comment: Well it was a somewhat facetious way of putting it, but I was seriously curious about what you meant.  It's not possible to time the lights in four directions on an urban scale.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a [Green Wave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green_wave). Co-ordinating it on two-way streets with varying distances between the junctions is tricky.

Comment: I'd rather call it "coordinated green waves in all 4 directions".  Can you add a particular city where you think it's done well?

Comment: I don't believe you can have all four dimensions simultaneously. It's fundamentally not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure there's a ranking anywhere, but Manhattan would seem to do pretty well, and there's evidence to back it up.

[NY Daily News](http://www.nydailynews.com/new-york/manhattan/uber-driver-catches-240-green-lights-potential-world-record-article-1.2926082) reported that an uber driver hit a 'record' 240 green lights in a row driving in Manhattan, and recorded the event as well.

Comment: Thanks, and good reference.  I'd guess these streets have a 30 mph limit, so I'm still looking for something faster...

Comment: Streets with 40mph limits are effectively small highways, and urban areas don't have large grids of 40mph streets, because that would be horribly unsafe. Since [traffic congestion increases to match the capacity of roads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_demand), it's near impossible to have sustain this for long during peak traffic time, as traffic jams will soon slow things down to the point where you're missing lights again.

Answer (score 1):

It is mathematically impossible to do even for both directions at once, as you cannot control the distances between traffic lights: the 'green waves' need to travel with you, at the same speed, and at the same time the ones for the opposite direction needs to travel too, but in the opposite direction. They simply will not hit each other exactly at all crossings, which makes it useless. Unless you want all cross traffic to stop for ten minutes.

Comment: I wish we hadn't started with the word "wave" because that is misleading.  You can go both directions if the frequency for the light switching is exactly the time it takes to drive from light to light at 40 mph.

Comment: @bobuhito that's impossible at urban scales.

Comment: It might work in some cities which have standard size blocks, (like some in the USA.) In most of the world you will find the blocks less equal in size.

Comment: If you do the math, and assume one minute green and one minute red, the traffic lights need to be ~1.5 miles apart for that to work. I don't know any city with traffic light that far apart.

Comment: So, do 10 seconds green, 10 seconds red, and it's reasonable.  Please don't give up so easily.

Comment: @bobuhito , it's not about giving up, it's about showing you it's _impossible_. For the typical city block of 1/10 mile, you would need 4 seconds green and 4 seconds red. Now consider you are not the only car on the road. You need to select a _single direction_, and then it's easy, and pretty much standard in many cities - in the morning inwards, in the evenings outwards, as the main rush-hour stream goes. Stop tooting the horn for an impossible idea, and read up on what is being done. There's a whole science of traffic control.

Comment: @Aganju Safety is the reason it's never done (or almost never, which is why I asked the question in the first place).  Notice also I did not require 1/10 mile blocks.